# Repeated errors when passing arguments in functions

Tags: c, function

In my program I have encountered the same 2 errors countless times. Here's a sliver of the program to illustrate the problem:

```
void update_table(char ary[SIZE][SIZE], int row, int column, char token)
{

if(token == 'X')
    ary[row][column] = 'X';
else if(token == 'O')
    ary[row][column] = 'O';


}
```

...

```
void generate_player2_move(char a[SIZE][SIZE], int rw, int cn)
{
char type = 'X';
srand(time(NULL));
rw = rand() % 3;
cn = rand() % 3;


    while(check_legal_option(a[SIZE][SIZE], rw, cn) == 1)
    {

    rw = rand() %3;
    cn = rand() %3;

    }
printf("Player 2 has entered [row, col]: %d,%d", rw, cn);
update_table(a[SIZE][SIZE], rw, cn, type);
display_table(a[SIZE][SIZE]);
}
```

and these are the two types of errors I have been getting:

```
note: expected ‘char (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 void update_table(char ary[SIZE][SIZE], int row, int column, char token)
```

and

```
  warning: passing argument 1 of ‘update_table’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] update_table(a[SIZE][SIZE], rw, cn, type);
```

I am confused about the first error, because I thought the argument is `char * [3]`, and then I don't quite understand the second error.

Comment: Just pass it as `update_table(a)`

Comment: `update_table(a[SIZE][SIZE], rw, cn, type);` => `update_table(a, rw, cn, type);`

Comment: so you don't pass the size of an array in a function?

Comment: @ClockwerkSC the name of a variable is its name

Comment: @ClockwerkSC no... `a[SIZE][SIZE]` doesn't pass the size. It passes the single element in the matrix at that location, which in your case is likely past the end of allocated space.  For example, if you declare an array like `int a[10][10];` then the elements are indexed from 0..9 in each dimension, so a[10][10] will be past the end of allocated space and give you an access violation.

Comment: What you pass [when you call a function] is different than the called function's declaration. When you do `update_table(a[SIZE][SIZE])` you are passing a _scalar_ value [and _not_ a _pointer_ to the `a` array as you desire]. FYI, This scalar is actually out-of-bounds for the array anyway (the last value would be `a[SIZE - 1][SIZE - 1]`). To pass the array's address, do [as others have suggested], `update_table(a)` which is [more or less] the same as `update_table(&a[0][0])`

Comment: Oh wow this makes complete and total sense, thank you guys for the clear and detailed explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `a[SIZE][SIZE]` instead of just `a` when calling `check_legal_option()`, `update_table()`, and `display_table()`.

`a[SIZE][SIZE]` attempts to access `a`'s element in row `SIZE` and column `SIZE`, which would take you out of bounds; you only need to declare `SIZE` in any function declaration that accepts `a` as a parameter.

Comment: So you don't pass the size of an array in a function?

Comment: No, you only pass in the array itself. If you need to pass in its size, you'd have to do that as a separate parameter.

Comment: Thank you guys, this cleared up the confusion that I had

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to your generate_player2_move function is declared as char a[SIZE][SIZE].  Apparently you are trying to pass a 2 dimensional array of chars.  However, when you pass an array you are actually passing a pointer to the 1st element in the array.  You are not passing the array itself.  Therefore, because a 2 dimensional array is really an array of arrays, the declaration of the parameter should really be a pointer to an array an array of SIZE characters.  The parameter should be declared as follows: char (*a)[SIZE]